# Passing variables to the same include that appears multiple times

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass variables in an include that appears on a page multiple times. While the following sample may technically work, I'm sure there is a much better way of doing this. Any help would be appreciated.

**index.php**

```
<?php 
    $user_avatar         = "user-1-avatar.jpg";
    $user_username       = "username-1";
    $user_name           = "User 1";

    include '/_user-card.php';
?>

<?php 
    $user_avatar         = "user-2-avatar.jpg";
    $user_username       = "username-2";
    $user_name           = "User 2";

    include '/_user-card.php';
?>
```

**_user-card.php**

```
<div class="user-card">
    <img src="<?php echo $user_avatar; ?>" alt="">
    <p class="user-card__username"><?php echo $user_username; ?></p>
    <p class="user-card__name"><?php echo $user_name; ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You could convert the include into a function and just call it repeatedly with the different parameters.

Comment: That example works, but can introduce security issues by outputting variables without sanitization. You may want to look into PHP template libraries. A list of those can be found here, for example: https://www.dunebook.com/best-php-template-engine/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create data that you can use over and over again by using the following function.

```php
function get_user_card($params = array()){
   $output = '';
   extract($params);
   if( isset($user_avatar) && isset($user_username) && isset($user_name) ) {
      ob_start();
      ?>
<div class="user-card">
    <img src="<?php echo $user_avatar; ?>" alt="">
    <p class="user-card__username"><?php echo $user_username; ?></p>
    <p class="user-card__name"><?php echo $user_name; ?></p>
</div>
      <?php
      $output = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
   }
   return $output;
}
```

```php
$user_1 = get_user_card(
  array(
    "user_avatar" => "user-1-avatar.jpg",
    "user_username" => "username-1",
    "user_name" => "User 1"
  )
);

echo $user_1;
```